# Localization of symmetric monoidal category

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, localization

Let $\mathcal M$ be a symmetric monoidal category, $S\subset \mathcal M$ a collection of objects and morphisms. I would like to construct the localization $\mathcal M \mathop{\longrightarrow}^T \mathcal M[S^{-1}]$, defined by

1. for each $x\in S$, there is $y\in\mathcal M[S^{-1}]$ such that $Tx\otimes y \cong I$;
2. for each $x \mathop{\longrightarrow}^f y \in S$, $Tf$ is an isomorphism in $\mathcal M[S^{-1}]$;
3. maybe there are some coherence conditions on the above;
4. $T$ is the universal symmetric monoidal functor with these properties.

Is there a reference which covers this construction and its properties?

Comment: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/localization#in_higher_category_theory Here it says that localization has higher dimensional analogues. However, it refers only to (infinity,1) localization. So, I don't if a general higher categorical localization is meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Localising with respect to morphisms is fairly standard.  Assuming that the tensor product of two morphisms in $S$ is again in $S$, the localised category should inherit a symmetric monoidal structure, just by the universal property.

Localising with respect to objects is Quillen's $\mathcal{A}^{-1}\mathcal{A}$ construction.  This is explained in Grayson's paper "Higher algebraic K-theory. II (after Daniel Quillen)", for example.  To avoid making mistakes with this, you should also read Thomason's paper "Beware the phony multiplication on Quillen's $\mathcal{A}^{-1}\mathcal{A}$".

Answer (score 1):

A reference regarding the monoidal structure on $M[S^{-1}]$ is Brian Day's [Note on monoidal localisations](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700045433). It also talks about the enriched setting, and about monoidal completion.