# Localization of a symmetric monoidal category is monoidal when the morphisms being inverted are closed under tensor product

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, localization

In the answer to question [Localization of symmetric monoidal category](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/176954/localization-of-symmetric-monoidal-category), it was mentioned that '' Assuming that the tensor product of two morphisms in $S$ is again in $S$, the localised category should inherit a symmetric monoidal structure, just by the universal property.''

So I want to know by which universal property we can show that $\mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]$ inherit a symmetric monoidal structure?

Since I cannot comment on the original answer, I posted this as a new (stupid) question.

Comment: I would appreciate it a lot if you could favour to answer this question..@Neil Strickland

Comment: You may would like to ask this question on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) instead. Anyway, the assumption that $S$ is closed with respect to the monoidal product $\otimes$ implies that the composition of the localisation functor $L_S:\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]$ with $\otimes$ sends a pair morphisms $(s,t)$ in $S\times S$ to an isomorphisms in $\mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]$. Thus, the composition $L_S\circ \otimes$ factorises through $L_S\times L_S$, defining the desired monoidal product on $\mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]\times\mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]$.

Comment: The universal property used here is that of the functor $L_S\times L_S:\mathcal{M}\times\mathcal{M}\to \mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]\times\mathcal{M}[S^{-1}]$.

Comment: @user337830 Your explanation is very understandable, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Note that using the "@" here will not send a notification to Neil Strickland, since he has nothing to do with this post.

Answer (score 2):

A reference regarding the monoidal structure on $M[S^{-1}]$ is Brian Day's [Note on monoidal localisations](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0004972700045433). It also talks about the enriched setting, and about monoidal completion. It includes a proof of Neil Strickland's point about requiring $S$ to be closed under $\otimes$, from the other MO thread you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

When $S=\mathcal{C}$, it is fairly straightforward to define a symmetric monoidal
structure on the groupoid completion $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}:=\mathcal{C}\left[ S^{-1} \right]$. I
couldn't find a reference for this fact, so I'll write it out in this answer.
The goal is to prove the following claim: *the groupoid completion of a symmetric
monoidal category is a symmetric monoidal category*.

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small symmetric monoidal category and let $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$ denote the
groupoid completion of $\mathcal{C}$. By the universal property of the groupoid
completion, this defines a functor $\mathcal{G}(-): \mathbf{Cat}\to \mathbf{Gpd}$, to the
category of small groupoids. This functor is left-adjoint:
for any small category $\mathcal{D}$ and any small groupoid $\mathcal{E}$, there
is a natural bijection of sets:
\begin{equation}\label{eq adj}
  \mathbf{Gpd}(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E}) \cong \mathbf{Cat}(\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E}),
\end{equation}
(This is just the universal property.) In fact, this bijection can be enriched to an isomorphism of categories:

**Equation 1**
\begin{equation}
    \underline{ \mathbf{Gpd} }(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D},\mathcal{E}) \cong \underline{ \mathbf{Cat} }(\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E}).
    \end{equation}

By virtue of being a left-adjoint, the functor $\mathcal{G}(-)$ preserves arbitrary colimits.
It turns out that it also preserves finite products:

**Lemma 1:**
  For any pair of small categories $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$, there is a natural isomorphism $\mathcal{G}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D})\cong\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D}$.

**Proof:**
  The proof is purely formal. By the Yoneda lemma, it suffices to exhibit a natural isomorphism between the functors represented by $\mathcal{G}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D})$ and $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D}$. For any groupoid $\mathcal{E}$, we have natural isomorphisms
  \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
      \mathbf{Gpd}(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E}) & \cong \mathbf{Gpd} (\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}, \underline{ \mathbf{Gpd} }(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E}))& \text{by the exponential law for groupoids}\\
      & \cong \mathbf{Cat}(\mathcal{C}, \underline{ \mathbf{Gpd} }(\mathcal{G}\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E})) & \text{by the uni. prop. of $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$}\\
      & \cong \mathbf{Cat}(\mathcal{C}, \underline{ \mathbf{Cat} }(\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E})) & \text{by eq. 1 }\\
      & \cong \mathbf{Cat}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}, \mathcal{E})& \text{by the exponential law for categories}\\
      & \cong \mathbf{Gpd}(\mathcal{G}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}), \mathcal{E})& \text{by the uni. prop. of $\mathcal{G}(\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D})$}.
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation*}

Explicitly, the above isomorphism simply makes morphisms of the form $q_{\mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D}}(f,g)$ correspond to morphisms of the form $(q_\mathcal{C}(f), q_{\mathcal{D}}(g))$.

Now given a symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{C}$ with tensor product $\otimes$, we
define a functor $\otimes'$ as the following composite:

[Diagram 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdM5X.png)

In order to show that $\otimes'$ is part of a symmetric monoidal structure on
$\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$, first observe the following.

**Remark:**
  Consider the following diagram:

[Diagram 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKho4.png)

Here the square commutes by definition of $\mathcal{G}(\otimes)$, and the triangle commutes by definition of $\otimes'$.
Using the explicit description of the isomorphism, we see that commutativity of the above diagram indicates that we have
\begin{equation}
 q_\mathcal{C}(f\otimes g) = q_\mathcal{C} (f) \otimes' q_\mathcal{C} (g),
\end{equation}
for any pair of morphisms $f$ and $g$ in $\mathcal{C}$.

Finally we have the following:

**Proposition:**
  The groupoid completion of a symmetric monoidal category is a symmetric monoidal category.

**Proof:**
  Let $(\mathcal{C}, \otimes, e, \alpha, \lambda, \rho, \gamma)$ be a symmetric monoidal category.
  The symmetric monoidal structure on the groupoid completion $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$ is given by $(\otimes', e, q_\mathcal{C}(\alpha), q_\mathcal{C}(\lambda), q_\mathcal{C}(\rho), q_\mathcal{C}(\gamma))$.

The fact that this indeed defines a symmetric monoidal structure follows from
  the remark.
  To illustrate, we verify the triangle axiom.
  Let $a$ and $c$ be objects in $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$ (\ie objects in $\mathcal{C}$).
  The triangle axiom for $\mathcal{C}$ states that the following diagram commutes.

[Diagram 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdrV3.png)

Applying the functor $q_\mathcal{C}$, we see that the following diagram commutes.

[Diagram 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWe0a.png)

Here we have used that $q_\mathcal{C}(1\otimes\lambda)=1\otimes
 q_\mathcal{C}(\lambda)$ and
 $q_\mathcal{C}(\rho\otimes1)=q_\mathcal{C}(\rho)\otimes 1$, which follows
 from the remark and functoriality of $q_\mathcal{C}$.
 This verifies the triangle axiom for $\mathcal{G}\mathcal{C}$, and the other axioms are verified similarly.